# Spring @Transactional Annotation : Self Invocation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, self-invoking-function

I know when a transactional method is called from inside the same class it wouldn't be run in a transaction. Spring creates a proxy for transactional methods and wraps them in a try-catch block and rolls back if an exception occurs. Consider the following scenario:

```
@Transactional
public void saveAB(A a, B b)
{
    saveA(a);
    saveB(b);
}

@Transactional
public void saveA(A a)
{
    dao.saveA(a);
}

@Transactional
public void saveB(B b)
{
    dao.saveB(b);
}
```

Assume `saveAB` is called from another object and an exception occurred in `saveB`, so `saveA` completed successfully but `saveB` did not. To my knowledge even though `saveA` and `saveB` are not transactional (because they are called from the same object), since `saveAB` is transactional it should still roll back.

What I don't understand is why do people say self invocation breaks transaction? As long as the caller method is transactional shouldn't everything work as expected? Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Your outer method is annotated so there is no problem. However if the outer method wouldn't be annotated you would have a problem as there would be no transaction nor for `saveA` nor for `saveB`. self invocation is a problem in that situation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> What I don't understand is why do people say self invocation breaks
>   transaction?

I never heard that self-invocation breaks transaction. All I know is that self-invocation will not start a new transaction and you already mentioned the reason why.

**Snippet from Spring's Transaction Management Specification**

> **Note** In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
>   coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
>   self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling
>   another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual
>   transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
>   @Transactional.

---

If you remove `@Transaction` annotation from `saveAB()`, you would observe that method `saveA()` and `saveB()` would not run under transaction even though it is annotated with `@Transactional`. However, if you call `saveA()` or `saveB()` from outside the class, it will run under transaction as expected. That is the reason why people advice to be cautious with self-invocation.

```
public void saveAB(A a, B b)
{
    saveA(a);
    saveB(b);
}

@Transactional
public void saveA(A a)
{
    dao.saveA(a);
}

@Transactional
public void saveB(B b)
{
    dao.saveB(b);
}
```

In my view, self-invoking any public method is a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

If you call `saveAB` and `saveB` throws an `Exception`, your transaction will roll back.

Self-invocation doesn't break the transactional context because the default transaction propagation is `REQUIRED`, meaning that the same transaction context is reused when calling a new `@Transactional` method on a new bean.

However, inside the same bean, calling new methods doesn't go through the `TransactionalInterceptor`, hence the very same transaction context is reused.