# Why Spring is commiting transaction here?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I have below method call hierarchy

```
public class UpdateProcess   { 

       public void startingMethod(List<Object> objects){
          for (Object obj : objects) {
              method1(obj);
           }
       }

        @Transactional
        public void method1(Object obj) {
            method2(obj);
        }


        public void method2(Object obj) {
           EmployeeService.updateObject(obj)
        }
    }   

public class EmployeeService

    @Transactional
    public void updateObject(Object obj) {

        return customerDao.update(obj);
    }


  }
```

In  above scenario, My expectation is  spring should commit the transaction as thread comes out of Method1 or rollback if exception occurs anywhere in hierarchy.

But spring is committing the transaction as soon as update is executed in method2. I am not getting why ?

**UPDATE:-** Even if I  change `@Transactional` to `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`  its still committing the transaction. So No impact

Comment: Please post proper code if you want to get answers.

Comment: @Kayaman I have posted the relevant code.  Is there any specific stuff you are looking for here ?

Comment: That code won't even compile, so it's clearly not the real code and it would be useless to comment on it.

Comment: What about posting some classes rather than a random bunch of methods.

Comment: @AlanHay complete code is too big(too big classes/XML configuration). If you can guys can provide the direction where can be the problem , it will be really helpful or if you are looking for specific stuff, I can post it

Comment: @Kayaman extremely sorry. I am not sure how come I missed it. Corrected it.

Comment: @emilly It looks a bit odd. Do you have an ongoing transaction when you're entering `method1()`? In any case, if you're making a call to it from the same object (e.g. from `startingMethod()`), the annotation won't be processed at all since it's a local method call that can't be intercepted. Calling `updateObject()` works because you're making a method call to another object, it will be intercepted and the transaction mechanism will be handled.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931698/spring-transactional-annotation-self-invocation and http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

Comment: Is your EmployeeService declared as interface or concrete class in UpdateProcess?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin EmployeeService  is an interface

Comment: @Kayaman Perfect. I got your point. Is there a way I can make self invocation method(in this case method1) Transactional or I have to move it to separate class ? I don't want to make  `startingMethod` Transactional as I want to  commit per object instead on collection

Comment: @emilly It's usually a better idea to redesign so you don't need to do the tricks required for self invocation. You should have a layered architecture anyway, that way it's harder to run into this problem (as well as getting additional advantages).

Comment: @Thankyou kayaman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Proxy-based Spring AOP, calling another method on the same object does not cause aspects to get applied.  The implementation of @Transactional for UpdateProcess would be created in a proxy that resides between UpdateProcess and other beans.  So if you call the method from "inside" the bean instead of "outside" of it, the call does not pass through the proxy and the aspects are not applied.