# what is the canonical way of using different tables of the same database in the same transaction?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions, crud-repository

To access two different tables in the same database, I use two dedicated CrudRepositories:

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Project, String> {
   public Project findByCode(ProjectCode code);     
}

public interface ProjectEventRepository extends CrudRepository<ProjectEventDo, String> {}
```

In my service class, I need to write to both of them in the same transaction:

```
@Transactional
public void deleteProject( String code) throws NoSuchCodedItemException {

    ProjectCode pCode= new ProjectCode(code);
    Project project = this.projectRepo.findByCode(pCode);
    if( project != null ) {
        this.projectRepo.save(project);
        project.getEvents().forEach(event -> {
            this.eventRepo.save(ProjectEventDo.of(event));
        });
    }

    throw new NoSuchCodedItemException(code);
}
```

What I would like to do instead, is factor this out to a common method of the service class like so:

```
@Transactional
public void persist(Project project) {
    this.projectRepo.save(project);
    project.getEvents().forEach(event -> {
        this.eventRepo.save(ProjectEventDo.of(event));
    });
}


public void deleteProject( String code) throws NoSuchCodedItemException {

    ProjectCode pCode= new ProjectCode(code);
    Project project = this.projectRepo.findByCode(pCode);
    if( project != null ) {
        this.persist(project);
    }

    throw new NoSuchCodedItemException(code);
}
```

This is along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612558/forcing-different-spring-repositories-to-use-the-same-transaction/76635300#76635300) answer to same kind of problem. However, it throws this warning:

```
@Transactional self-invocation (in effect, a method within the target object calling
another method of the target object) does not lead to an actual transaction at runtime
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931698/spring-transactional-annotation-self-invocation) accepted answer, the point is made to avoid self-invoking public methods, and indeed it is public only to please the @Transactional annotation, which requires it.

Is there a way to do the refactoring?

Answer (score 0):

It appears both methods need the @Transactional, to avoid the warning.
Duhh. Should have seen this.

Still leaves us with the itch of a purely internal method (`persist`) made public only for the JPA mechanism.